# How do I import CSV file into a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I have an unnormalized events-diary CSV from a client that I'm trying to load into a MySQL table so that I can refactor into a sane format. I created a table called 'CSVImport' that has one field for every column of the CSV file. The CSV contains 99 columns , so this was a hard enough task in itself:

```
CREATE TABLE 'CSVImport' (id INT);
ALTER TABLE CSVImport ADD COLUMN Title VARCHAR(256);
ALTER TABLE CSVImport ADD COLUMN Company VARCHAR(256);
ALTER TABLE CSVImport ADD COLUMN NumTickets VARCHAR(256);
...
ALTER TABLE CSVImport Date49 ADD COLUMN Date49 VARCHAR(256);
ALTER TABLE CSVImport Date50 ADD COLUMN Date50 VARCHAR(256);
```

No constraints are on the table, and all the fields hold VARCHAR(256) values, except the columns which contain counts (represented by INT), yes/no (represented by BIT), prices (represented by DECIMAL), and text blurbs (represented by TEXT).

I tried to load data into the file:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/home/paul/clientdata.csv' INTO TABLE CSVImport;
Query OK, 2023 rows affected, 65535 warnings (0.08 sec)
Records: 2023  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 198256
SELECT * FROM CSVImport;
| NULL             | NULL        | NULL           | NULL | NULL               | 
...
```

The whole table is filled with `NULL`.

I think the problem is that the text blurbs contain more than one line, and MySQL is parsing the file as if each new line would correspond to one databazse row. I can load the file into OpenOffice without a problem.

The clientdata.csv file contains 2593 lines, and 570 records. The first line contains column names. I think it is comma delimited, and text is apparently delimited with doublequote.

UPDATE:

When in doubt, read the manual: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

I added some information to the `LOAD DATA` statement that OpenOffice was smart enough to infer, and now it loads the correct number of records:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/home/paul/clientdata.csv"
INTO TABLE CSVImport
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

But still there are lots of completely `NULL` records, and none of the data that got loaded seems to be in the right place.

Comment: And if you're on OSX [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) has an awesome import tool and it's **FREE** ;-)

Comment: It's amazing to me that the original poster answered his own question better than anyone else... I don't know why so many people are so ready to give software recommendations when there is an existing SQL command, which can be *programmatic* rather than UI-based. I don't know about anyone else, but programmatic means to me that I can have scripts set up to auto-import files on timestamps, whereas UI-based is purely manual.

Comment: @ChrisCirefice: I think the accepted answer explains that well. He needed some help manually creating the 'load data' command, which a graphical program can help with. Once the graphical program had created the 'load data' command, he could then reuse it programmatically.

Comment: @Merrick this worked a treat on osx

Comment: I wrote extensive tutorial to [load csv data into mysql](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/load-delimited-data-csv-excel-into-mysql-server) along with a [syntax generator tool in Excel](http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/mysql-load-data-infile-syntax-generator-tool).

Comment: @ChrisCirefice scripts are awesome for repeated events; but GUIs are better for one-time things, because you don't have to figure out all the esoteria just to do the one thing one time

Comment: The "OPTIONALLY" was what was causing me problems. I had omitted it.

Answer (score 151, accepted):

The core of your problem seems to be matching the columns in the CSV file to those in the table.

Many graphical mySQL clients have very nice import dialogs for this kind of thing.

My favourite for the job is Windows based [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/). It gives you a graphical interface to build the `LOAD DATA` command; you can re-use it programmatically later.

[image: Import textfile]

[Screenshot: "Import textfile" dialog](http://www.heidisql.com/screenshots.php?which=import_textfile)

To open the Import textfile" dialog, go to `Tools > Import CSV file`:

[image]

Comment: For Mac OSX, use Sequel Pro.

Comment: I just tried it and it requires me to create the table first... instead of using the column names.

Comment: @Dominique that shouldn't happen. What message are you getting exactly? Are you seeing the columns from the first line in the CSV in the import dialog?

Comment: You have to select a table before you can continue... and since the whole point is not having to make the table...

Comment: Check your own screenshot, you'll see!

Comment: @Dominique oh, you're right of course, what you want the import dialog can't do. Here is one solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998596/create-mysql-table-directly-from-csv-file-using-the-csv-storage-engine

Comment: Note that in Linux, HeidiSQL works very well under Wine.

Comment: Dont know why this is top answer because it requires use of gui tool

Comment: @Paul the very *point* of the answer is that GUI tools can make matching import columns to table columns easier.

Comment: @Pekka but the question didnt ask for a gui tool and if accessing a remote database that you have only access to via a linux terminal window these gui tools are no help. Even if you have access you still have the hassle of installing and getting gui tool up and running

Comment: @Paul there are several dozen other answers to this question that do not require installing a GUI tool. You'll find them right underneath this one. (This is the top answer because the asker thought it was the most useful to them and they marked it "accepted.")

Comment: @Pekka, great thats fine, for me it was not a useful answer and did not directly answer the question and so I marked it down.

Comment: @Paul that's your prerogative, of course. 92 people apparently felt it answers the question...

Answer (score 232):

Use [mysqlimport](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/mysqlimport.html) to load a table into the database:

```sh
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1 \
            --fields-terminated-by=, \
            --local -u root \
            -p Database \
             TableName.csv
```

I found it at http://chriseiffel.com/everything-linux/how-to-import-a-large-csv-file-to-mysql/

To make the delimiter a tab, use `--fields-terminated-by='\t'`

Comment: `mysqlimport` uses `LOAD DATA INFILE...` behind the scenes, so it's pretty much the same thing.

Comment: As with `LOAD DATA INFILE`, you need to create a table before you can use `mysqlimport`.

Comment: @MladenJablanović, it's definitely not the same thing. Try importing 1bil rows. You'll be surprised what a massive difference it makes in terms of performance

Comment: @ninjabber The docs [says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html) _The mysqlimport client provides a command-line interface to the LOAD DATA INFILE_, so it is **theoretically** impossible to offer any performance benefit over `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

Comment: also need `--fields-optionally-enclosed-by=\"` and `--fields-escaped-by=\\`

Comment: Should be correct answer. Talks about CLI like the question was dicussing, as opposed to a GUI.

Comment: @ninjabber Do you have any performance test?

Comment: This is the easiest solution among all others. Thank you so much.

Comment: I got Error: 1205, Lock wait timeout exceeded when using mysqlimport to import a big txt (30G), any suggesstions?

Answer (score 98):

Simplest way which I have imported 200+ rows is below command in phpmyadmin sql window

I have a simple table of country with two columns
CountryId,CountryName

here is .csv data[image: CSV FILE]

here is command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/country.csv' 
INTO TABLE country 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

Keep one thing in mind, never appear , in second column, otherwise your import will stop

Comment: ',' -> '\t', '"' -> '' in case of TSV files and remove the last line if no header. (hope search crawlers index this).

Comment: If it's a local file, you might need to `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. If this throws an error 1148 "used command is not allowed", you can enable it by running mysql on the command line with `--local-infile`.

Comment: i got the error :  ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: You must grant all access to the user,  from admin panel then, try importing the script.

Comment: I am getting this error: The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Comment: perfect answer just run it with `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` and all is fine

Comment: Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

Answer (score 91):

I Used this method to import more than 100K records (**~5MB**) in **0.046sec**

Here's how you do it:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  
'c:/temp/some-file.csv'
INTO TABLE your_awesome_table  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(field_1,field_2 , field_3);
```

It is very important to include the last line , if you have more than one field i.e normally it skips the last field   (MySQL 5.6.17)

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(field_1,field_2 , field_3);
```

Then, assuming you have the **first row as the title** for your fields, you might want to include this line also

```
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

This is what it looks like if your file has a header row.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE  
'c:/temp/some-file.csv'
INTO TABLE your_awesome_table  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(field_1,field_2 , field_3);
```

Comment: I imported 16k rows and 48 columns. Thank you, buddy.

Comment: This is the best solution. For anyone curious how fast this is: I imported 3.2 million rows in under 14 secs on a $20/mo AWS Lightsail instance, with the onboard MySQL server (not a high performance RDS). Awesome!

Comment: In this line, `(field_1,field_2 , field_3);` does it refer to the list of columns in a .csv file or in a table? i.e., what are these fields?

Comment: @tera_789 The ones in your csv file that will probably match your table

Answer (score 36):

**phpMyAdmin** can handle CSV import. Here are the steps:

1. Prepare the CSV file to have the fields in the same order as the MySQL table fields.
2. Remove the header row from the CSV (if any), so that only the data is in the file.
3. Go to the phpMyAdmin interface.
4. Select the table in the left menu.
5. Click the import button at the top.
6. Browse to the CSV file.
7. Select the option "CSV using LOAD DATA".
8. Enter "," in the "fields terminated by".
9. Enter the column names in the same order as they are in the database table.
10. Click the go button and you are done.

This is a note that I prepared for my future use, and sharing here if someone else can benefit.

Comment: This is good and simple. I prefer creating tables and columns via SQL (so I skip Step #9) and inserting data via importing CSV. Do not forget to set `NULL` in the CSV for any auto-incrementing fields/columns.

Comment: Note that phpMyAdmin fails miserably when Cyrillic chars are included into the CSV file, no matter you tell it to use utf-8.

Comment: Don't forget to change the import size if you're importing large CSV file. BTW its not a good option for large CSV files.

Comment: This requires downloading the .csv file to a web client first as you cannot browse to a local csv file.

Comment: Yes you can, you need to check the checkbox marked 'Local Keyword' and you can use a local csv file

Comment: I was struggling with the 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden' error while using the SQL command. This method solved my issue. Easy and straight to the point.

Answer (score 18):

If you are using MySQL Workbench (currently 6.3 version) you can do this by:

1. Right click on "Tables";
2. Chose Table Data Import Wizard;
3. Chose your csv file and follow the instructions (JSON also could be used);
   The good thing is that you can create a new table based on the csv file you want to import or load data to an existing table

[image]

Comment: +1. I used this because mysql kept giving me errors for `LOAD DATA INFILE` and `mysqlimport` ("this is not supported on this version of mysql")

Comment: This method works, but it's kind of slow. I would have thought that using this feature would have built a massive `INSERT` query and tried to do it all at once, but it looks like doing it this way actually runs once `INSERT` per row.

Comment: This method saved me. I was getting a lot of errors with LOAD DATA, but in need of hurry. I highly recommend if any reader is having problems with LOAD DATA.

Comment: Using Workbench 8.0.22 this feature is far from stable. Keeps crashing, importing 0 lines or just freezes. Tried it with Our World in Data's COVID-19 CSV: https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/tree/master/public/data

Answer (score 13):

You can fix this by listing the columns in you LOAD DATA statement. From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'persondata.txt' INTO TABLE persondata (col1,col2,...);
```

...so in your case you need to list the 99 columns in the order in which they appear in the csv file.

Answer (score 8):

Try this, it worked for me

```
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filename.csv' INTO TABLE table_name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

IGNORE 1 ROWS here ignores the first row which contains the fieldnames. Note that for the filename you must type the absolute path of the file.

Comment: This is the best answer. Why use _another_ tool when a single SQL command will do?

Comment: Do- u know how to make this work when u r trying to load the file into mysql running on a server? It asks me access denied for the file (password). Where to enter password of csv file location?

Answer (score 8):

I see something strange. You are using for ESCAPING the same character you use for ENCLOSING. So the engine does not know what to do when it founds a '"' and I think that is why nothing seems to be in the right place.
I think that if you remove the line of ESCAPING, should run great. Like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "/home/paul/clientdata.csv"
INTO TABLE CSVImport
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

Unless you analyze (manually, visually, ... ) your CSV and find which character uses for escape. Sometimes is '\'. But if you do not have it, do not use it.

Answer (score 7):

The mysql command line is prone to too many problems on import. Here is how you do it:

- use excel to edit the header names to have no spaces
- save as .csv
- use free Navicat Lite Sql Browser to import and auto create a new table (give it a name)
- open the new table insert a primary auto number column for ID
- change the type of the columns as desired.
- done!

Answer (score 5):

Yet another solution is to use [csvsql](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/csvsql.html) tool from amazing [csvkit](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit) suite.

Usage example:

```
csvsql --db mysql://$user:$password@localhost/$database --insert --tables $tablename  $file
```

This tool can automatically infer the data types (default behavior), create table and insert the data into the created table. `--overwrite` option can be used to drop table if it already exists. `--insert` option — to populate the table from the file.

#### To install the suite

```
pip install csvkit
```

**Prerequisites:** `python-dev`, `libmysqlclient-dev`, `MySQL-python`

```
apt-get install python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
pip install MySQL-python
```

Answer (score 3):

In case if you using Intellij
https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/features/importexport.html

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I use mysql workbench to do the same job.

1. create new schema
2. open newly created schema
3. right click on "Tables" and select "Table Data Import Wizard"
4. give the csv file path and table name and finally configure your column type because the wizard set default column type based on their values.

Note: take a look at mysql workbench's log file for any errors by using "tail -f [mysqlworkbenchpath]/log/wb*.log"

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer - being new to MySQL I didn't know about this - it helped me with CSV. Now, I also need to import 10 tables from Access - do you think the simplest way will be to export these tables into Excel, from Excel to CSV and then use these steps?

Comment: I found that this method doesn't import all rows :( Out of 5,342 rows it only imported 2,485 rows for me. Why it that?

Comment: Hey Naomi, if you check the mysqlworkbench log it will show you why it stopped importing data. You may have some null values or mismatch type in your DB and CSV file. But I highly recommend to follow Juan's answer(right after me). His solution is better and cleaner than me.

Answer (score 3):

How to import csv files to sql tables

Example file: `Overseas_trade_index` data CSV File

Steps:

1. Need to create table for `overseas_trade_index`.
2. Need to create columns related to csv file.

   SQL Query:

   ```
   ( id int not null primary key auto_increment,
   series_reference varchar (60),
   period varchar (60),
   data_value decimal(60,0),
   status varchar (60),
   units varchar (60),
   magnitude int(60),
   subject text(60),
   group text(60),
   series_title_1 varchar (60),
   series_title_2 varchar (60),
   series_title_3 varchar (60),
   series_title_4 varchar (60),
   series_title_5 varchar (60),
    );
   ```
3. Need to connect mysql database in terminal.

   ```
   =>show databases;
   =>use database;
   =>show tables;
   ```
4. Please enter this command to import the csv data to mysql tables.

   ```
   load data infile '/home/desktop/Documents/overseas.csv' into table trade_index fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' (series_reference,period,data_value,status,units,magnitude,subject,series_title1,series_title_2,series_title_3,series_title_4,series_title_5);
   ```
5. Find this overseas trade index data on sqldatabase:

   ```
   select * from trade_index;
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I know that my answer is late, but I'd like to mention a few other ways to do it.
The easiest one is using command line. The steps will be the following:

1. Accessing the MySQL CLI by entering the below command:

> mysql -u my_user_name -p

2. Creating a table in the database

> ```
> use new_schema;
>
> CREATE TABLE employee_details (
> id INTEGER,
> employee_name VARCHAR(100),
> employee_age INTEGER,
> PRIMARY KEY (id)
> );
> ```

3. Importing the CSV file into a table. We can either mention the file path or store the file in the default directory of the MySQL server.

> ```
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'Path to the exported csv file'
> INTO TABLE employee_details
> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
> IGNORE 1 ROWS;
> ```

It's the only one of many solutions, I found it in this [tutorial](https://skyvia.com/blog/how-to-import-csv-file-into-mysql-table-in-4-different-ways)
If loading CSV files into MySQL database is your daily task, then it'll be better to automate this process. In this case you can use some 3rd-party tools that allows you to load data in schedule.

Comment: I just want to mention the **CSV Lint plug-in** for Notepad++ https://github.com/BdR76/CSVLint It's a freeware tool and it can automatically generate the `CREATE TABLE` statement with the correct column datatypes based on the data, and convert all the csv data into `INSERT` statements.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a windows machine with Excel spreadsheet loaded, the new mySql plugin to Excel is phenomenal.  The folks at Oracle really did a nice job on that software.  You can make the database connection directly from Excel.  That plugin will analyse your data, and set up the tables for you in a format consistent with the data. I had some monster big csv files of data to convert.  This tool was a big time saver.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/excel/

You can make updates from within Excel that will populate to the database online.  This worked exceedingly well with mySql files created on ultra inexpensive GoDaddy shared hosting.  (Note when you create the table at GoDaddy, you have to select some off-standard settings to enable off site access of the database...)

With this plugin you have pure interactivity between your XL spreadsheet and online mySql data storage.

Answer (score 2):

I did it in simple way using phpmyadmin. I followed the steps by @Farhan but all data were eltered in single column.
How I did:

1. Created a CSV file and deleted the header row with column names. Kept only data.
2. I created a table with column names matching the csv columns.
3. Remember to assign appropriate types to each column.
4. I just selected the import and went to import tab.
5. In browse I selected the CSV file and kept all options as it is.
6. To my surprise all the data got imported successfully in their appropriate columns.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP Query for import csv file to mysql database**

```
$query = <<<EOF
            LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'
             INTO TABLE users
             FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
             LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
             IGNORE 1 LINES
            (name,mobile,email)
    EOF;
if (!$result = mysqli_query($this->db, $query))
   {
        exit(mysqli_error($this->db));
   }
```

**Sample CSV file data **

```
name,mobile,email
Christopher Gritton,570-686-3439,ChristopherKGritton@inbound.plus
Brandon Wilson,541-309-5149,BrandonMWilson@inbound.plus
Craig White,516-795-8065,CraigJWhite@inbound.plus
David Whitney,713-214-3966,DavidCWhitney@inbound.plus
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample excel file screen shot:

[image]

Save as  and choose .csv.

And you will have as shown below .csv data screen shot if you open using notepad++ or any other notepad.

[image]

Make sure you remove header and have column alignment in .csv as in mysql Table.
Replace folder_name by your folder name

**LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

'D:/folder_name/myfilename.csv'
INTO TABLE mail 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
(fname,lname ,email, phone);**

If big data, you can take coffee and have it load!.

Thats all you need.

Answer (score 1):

> Change servername,username, password,dbname,path of your file, tablename and the field which is in your database you want to insert

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "bd_dashboard";
    //For create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
                'C:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/my_data.csv'
                INTO TABLE test_tab
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                IGNORE 1 LINES
                (name,mob)";
    if (!$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query)){
        echo '<script>alert("Oops... Some Error occured.");</script>';
        exit();
            //exit(mysqli_error());
       }else{
        echo '<script>alert("Data Inserted Successfully.");</script>'
       }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

When executing MySQL Query to import CSV I was getting error
'*Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement*'

So I moved file to secure file location

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Orders.csv'   
INTO TABLE orderdetails.orders 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
 ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
 IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

Where location of file is 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/Orders.csv' this is because, I moved my CSV file to 'secure_file_priv' location otherwise I was getting above error

You can get your secure_file_priv using query `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";`

Source: [Import CSV file to MySQL (Query or using Workbench)](https://qawithexperts.com/article/sql/import-csv-file-to-mysql-query-or-using-workbench/454)

Answer (score 0):

Hi Import csv in your mysql database using use teminal because if
data set in large then it's difficult to import data from file upload options.

Basically We have import data using table first create table in database.
after same table filed we have to create data from csv.

You have to add csv file **Navigate to the following directory: /var/lib/mysql-files** but if you not use root user then it can not direct goes to **/var/lib/mysql-files** so using ui first go to **/var/lib** then
click on **mysql-files** then enter your root user password. then copy the
your csv file which we import in table.

after you are login mysql in termianl and databse selected then fire below
syntex data

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/{your-csv-name}'
INTO TABLE {your-table-name}
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

For Example my table is sample and mycsv file is Sample.csv then below
reference

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/Sample.csv' INTO TABLE sample FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

For importing large amount of csv it's best way to use mysql terminal for
importing data in your database.

Please check sample for this link : [Mysql import data using csv using terminal or command line](https://myphpinformation.blogspot.com/2024/02/mysql-import-data-using-csv-using-terminal-or-command-line-cli.html)