# load data into an EAV table from a CSV file

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-attribute-value

How do I load data into an EAV table from a CSV file in MYSQL database?

My CSV file is like this:

```
"ID",    "attr1",    "attr2",    "attr3",
"ID1",   "value1",   "value2",   "value3",
```

I tried using a script to change the CSV file into EAV CSV file but I think that won't be scalable.

Comment: Does the table exist? It's not clear what you're asking...

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table

Comment: @rags The question you specified is not exactly the one I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making use of fgetcsv function in PHP ?. 
[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

Without showing what you have tried we could not able to help.

Comment: I tried using a script to change the CSV file into EAV CSV file but I think that won't be scalable.

Comment: @user1471283, EAV model breaks referential integrities and other complexities such as this. Is your MySQL DB designed on that way ?

Comment: Yes. It is built in that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should transform your usually CSV

```
Max;Mustermann;Hamburg;Am Elbufer 123
Jens;Mander;Manderscheid;Eisgasse 99
```

into another CSV with exact 3 fields like this:

```
addr01=name=Mustermann
addr01=vname=Max
addr01=ort=Hamburg
addr01=str=Am Elbufer 123
addr02=name=Mander
addr02=vname=Jens
addr02=ort=Manderscheid
addr02=str=Eisgasse 99
```

Now, always having 3 fields: Entity, Attribute, Value.

By the way, in Perl a Hash of Hashes, also means EAV:

```
$EAV = {
    addr01 = {
        name  => 'Mustermann',
        vname => 'Max',
        ort   => 'Hamburg',
        str   => 'Am Elbufer 123',
    },
    addr02 = {
        name  => 'Mander',
        vname => 'Jens',
        ort   => 'Manderscheid',
        str   => 'Eisgasse 99',
    },
};
```