# Creating records in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, records

I have 2 lists of postcodes, one origins and the other destinations:

### Origins

1. firstOrigin
2. secondOrigin
3. thirdOrigin

### Destinations

1. firstDestination
2. secondDestination
3. thirdDestination

I want to be able to import these to a mysql database so they are imported as single records for each journey. So the final results will be (where Origin and Destination are columns in the table):

### Origin Destination

firstOrigin firstDestination

---

firstOrigin secondDestination

---

firstOrigin thirdDestination

---

secondOrigin firstDestination

---

secondOrigin secondDestination

---

secondOrigin thirdDestination

---

thirdOrigin firstDestination

---

thirdOrigin secondDestination

---

thirdOrigin thirdDestination

---

Apologies if this is unclear. It's difficult to display a table on here!

Comment: in what format is your current data? for the db part you need to create a simple table with three columns `id, origin, destination`...

Comment: The database is setup correctly, it's for the end user. I would prefer them supply a list of origins in a csv file and a list of destinations in a csv file. To save them having to mess around with excel or some other program getting them in a correct format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this question for importing data from [CSV to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table). You have to have two tables `origins` and `distinations` or better yet create temporary tables `origins` and `distinations`. Once you have imported data in mysql, You can get your result by applying cross product on both tables like this

```
INSERT INTO yourResultingTable
    (origins, destinations)
    SELECT origins.origin, destination.destination FROM origins, destinations;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
INSERT INTO global_table (origin, destination)
SELECT origin_column, destination_column
FROM origin, destination
```