# LOAD DATA INFILE with a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, load-data-infile

I have the following database relationship:
[image]

I also have this large CSV file that I want to insert into `bmt_transcripts`:

```
Ensembl Gene ID Ensembl Transcript ID
ENSG00000261657 ENST00000566782
ENSG00000261657 ENST00000562780
ENSG00000261657 ENST00000569579
ENSG00000261657 ENST00000568242
```

The problem is that can't insert the Ensemble Gene ID as a string, I need to find its ID from the `bmt_genes` table, so I came up with this code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'filename.csv'
INTO TABLE `bmt_transcripts`
(@gene_ensembl, ensembl_id)
    SET gene_id = (SELECT id FROM bmt_genes WHERE ensembl_id = @gene_ensembl);
```

However this takes over 30 minutes to load a 7mb CSV, which is far too long. I assume it's running a table-wide query for every row it inserts, which is obviously horribly inefficient. I know I could load the data into a temporary table and SELECT from that (which, yes, runs in some 5 seconds), but this CSV may grow to have some 20 columns, which will become unwieldy to write a select statement for.

How can I fix my LOAD DATA INFILE query (which runs a SELECT on another table) to run in a reasonable length of time?

Comment: You can [import the CSV file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table) to a temporary table, and then run an efficient SQL query to get the data in place.

Comment: I mentioned that in the question. The CSV might become more than 20 columns. I'm not sure writing an INSERT INTO where I write out all 20 columns twice is a good idea

Comment: I have the same issue; for me it looks like MySql bug, because if I create `PHP` or `Python` script that does the same (parses file, runs subquery as separate query, and runs `INSERT`) works thousand times faster.