# How to import data from mongodb to MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, mongodb

More specifically , can i use some bridge for this like first i should copy data to excel fro mongodb and then that excel sheets data could easily be imported into mysql by some scripts like as in Python.

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#export-in-csv-format, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table - Does this help?

Comment: my question is importing data from mongodb to mysql . Can i get some stuff regarding this.

Comment: You can write a Python (or choose your favourite language) script that talks directly to both databases, or you could use command-line tools like [`mongoexport`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and [`mysqlimport`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html). Generally you'd want to consider different (and more appropriate) data models rather than just a straight copy between relational & non-relational databases. Going by way of Excel is completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB does not offer any direct tool to do this, but you have many options to achieve this.

You can:

- Write your own tool using your favorite language, that connect to MongoDB & MySQL and copy the data
- Use [mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#export-in-csv-format) to create files and [mysqlimport](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlimport.html) to reimport them into MySQL
- Use an ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) that connect to MongoDB, allow you to transform the data and push them into MySQL. You can for example use [Talend](http://talend.com) that has connector for MongoDB, bu you have many other solutions.

*Note:* Keep in mind that a simple document could contains complex structures such as Array/List, sub-documents, and even an Array of sub-documents. These structures can not be imported directly into a single table record, this is why most of the time you need a small transformation/mapping layer.