# how to work with mysqlimport.exe for csv in windows cmd or mysql cmd line utility

Tags: mysql, cmd

How to import data from CSV to mysql through cmd with mysqlimport.exe?

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/17071108/1788704

Comment: Thank you Kmas !  Please find the following code................ mysqlimport.exe "-L MYDB 'C:\myfolder\messagetemplate.csv' --host=myipaddress --user=myusername --password=mypwd --ignore-lines=1 --use-threads=5 --debug-info -C -f -i -l -v -s --lines-terminated-by='\r\n' --fields-terminated-by=, --fields-escaped-by=\\"                                            Iam not able to execute the above one in the cmd line or mysqluc  or mysqlcmdline.  Kindly provide the needful.        Satish