# Making a CSV field in a mysql table

Tags: mysql, csv

I know that you can make a field in a MySQL table a CSV type of field. But, I don't know anything about using it, writing to it, reading it, etc.

Is there information online somewhere? It's not in the large book on PHP/MySql that I bought which is kind of frustrating.

I'm needing to make a table within a table and I'm assuming a CSV field type is the way to do this?

Comment: I don't think there is a CSV data type. Generally, having a table within a table is a bad idea and there's likely to be a better way, what is it you want to build?

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table

Comment: Not a duplicate. But, I'm realizing I was mixing up fgetcsv with field types.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql does not have a CSV type.  You are either thinking of another database engine or possibly thinking of an enumerated datatype which, while it does not create a table within a table, is a dictionary of values.

Here are two links that provide more info on datatypes in Mysql:

[mysql-data-types](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-data-types.htm)

[dev.mysql/data-types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-types.html)

You can define your own datatypes in postgres. More info [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createtype.html). Although, I do not think that you can create a "csv (table within table) datatype".