# Load csv file into mysql database

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench, workbench, mysqlimport

I'm trying to load a big CSV file into mysql but couldn't find out why it fails.

My CSV file looks like this:

```
_id,"event","unit","created","r1","r2","r3","r4","space_id","owner_id","name","display_name","users__email"
565ce313819709476d7eaf0e,"create",3066,"2015-12-01T00:00:19.604Z","563f592dd6f47ae719be8b38","3","13","7","55ecdd4ea970e6665f7e3911","55e6e3f0a856461404a60fc1","household","household","foo.bar@ace.com"
565ce350819709476d7eaf0f,"complete",3067,"2015-12-01T00:01:19.988Z","21","","","","55e6df3ba856461404a5fdc9","55e6e3f0a856461404a60fc1","Ace","Base","foo.bar@ace.com"
565ce350819709476d7eaf0f,"delete",3067,"2015-12-01T00:01:19.988Z","21","","","","55e6df3ba856461404a5fdc9","55e6e3f0a856461404a60fc1","Ace","Base","foo.bar@ace.com"
565ce350819709476d7eaf0f,"update",3067,"2015-12-01T00:01:19.988Z","21","","","","55e6df3ba856461404a5fdc9","55e6e3f0a856461404a60fc1","Ace","Base","foo.bar@ace.com"
```

And my code to load the file into mysql is this one:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS analys;

USE analys;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS event_log (
  _id CHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  event_log VARCHAR(255),
  unit CHAR(4),
  created VARCHAR(255),
  r1 VARCHAR(255),
  r2 VARCHAR(255),
  r3 VARCHAR(255),
  r4 VARCHAR(255),
  space_id VARCHAR(255),
  owner_id VARCHAR(255),
  name VARCHAR(255),
  display_name VARCHAR(255),
  users__email VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (_id)
)

LOAD DATA INFILE 'audits.export.csv' 
INTO TABLE event_log
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n\r'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Everything is fine, including the query but I get `NULL` in every column (only one row).

Here is the Action Output:

```
22:31:21    LOAD DATA INFILE 'audits.export.csv'  INTO TABLE event_log FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n\r' IGNORE 1 ROWS   0 row(s) affected Records: 0  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0   0.156 sec
```

I tried to tweak the table and the load query but it doesn't work

I'm on Windows 7, using Mysql 5.6 and Workbench.
I heard about GUI solution or Excel connectors here ([Excel Connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table)) but I prefer to do it programmaticaly as I need to reuse the code.

Any help? I couldn't solve the problem with similar posts on Stackoverflow.

Comment: It can be data issue and it can be formatting issue ....take one of the rows and try to insert into mysql using insert into blah values ("Ace","Base","foo.bar@ace.com") .... and take it from there as a part of debugging process.  use "mysql workbench" or something

Comment: Check your file is not one line .... hence , you are saying LINES TERMINATED BY '\n\r'  .... you can do that like this : cat -vet filename.csv

Comment: I'm on windows and cat -vet doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This doens't seem a valid newline:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n\r'
```

change to:

```
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Or only one of them (could be single `\n` or `\r` depending on the system, or the software that created the csv file).

Comment: Same. I tweaked the code, especially this part as the encoding could have been done on Unix or Windows but it doesn't change anything. Good query but 0 rows affected

Comment: @Synleb - Strange. And the filename is correct too I assume? i.e. not needing a slash/backslash after audits (or a full path)?

Comment: @Synleb - I don't know if this is the case in your real data, but te primary key field contains duplicate values.

Comment: Path is correct and I tried with the bavkslash. It doesn't change anything. For the duplicate it's not the case in real data. I copy pasted the 2nd line.

Comment: With only the four lines I provided (without duplicates on _id) I get another error: **Error Code: 1261. Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns**

Comment: @Synleb - Are you sure there are no hidden characters in your data? (maybe manually type in a short one to test?) - (Long shot: maybe change _id to another name).

Comment: I iterated by removing fields in order to come to the simplest form of my audit log. If found out that the problem is the double quote `"`. If I keep my audit log as-is, it doesn't log anything. If I do a find and replace to remove all the double quotes, and it start loading. BUT: as I have some comas in strings, by removing the double quotes, I get another error **Error Code: 1262. Row 405 was truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns**

Answer (score 0):

Because some might come here wanting to know how to do this with MySQL Workbench:

1. Save CSV data to a file, for example foo.csv
2. Open MySQL Workbench
3. Choose/Open a MySQL Connection
4. Right-click on a schema in the Object Browser (left Navigator)
5. Choose "Table Data Import Wizard"
6. Select the CSV file, which is foo.csv in our example
7. Follow the wizard; many configuration options are available, including the separator
8. When finished, the CSV data will be in a new or existing table (your choice)

For additional information, see the documentation titled [Table Data Export and Import Wizard](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import-table.html).

I just tested this in the example data provided in the question, and it worked.

Comment: Thanks @Philip. But I'd rather like a code based solution  than a GUI one as I want to implement the loading in a script. I know the problem is the double quotes but I don't know why as double quotes are one of my parameters in the load query