# Import Records into MySQL Using vTiger

Tags: php, mysql, csv, sugarcrm, vtiger

Can someone suggest the best way to import CSV records in MySQL?

The following operation I would need to perform on every single row of a CSV file.

- Import CSV file
- Scheduler will run import script
- For each record
- Check id exists in third party app through API
- Insert into db if id not exists

How about if I use a batch to import the records into the DB? What's the best way to read a CSV file?

Please help.

Comment: Did you read what writes on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table ? Does that helps you?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But i want to call some API while importing. So I think just go ahead with batch import. But looking for better solution if any. Thanks