# importing CSV from SAP R/3 to SQL database for reporting purpose

Tags: sql, database, sap-r3

I want to import CSV files and invoices from SAP R/3 system into a SQL database. The database will be used for reporting purpose only, please tell me what will be the best possible way, which database to use and anything else that will be relevant to me in this context? and I am novice so please help....Thanks:)

Comment: Why aren't you use SAP for this?

Comment: Questions asking for opinions are kind of frowned upon. Likewise so is asking questions that already have answers. How to import CSV files into a database is a prertty hot topic, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table

Answer (score 0):

If you are routinely importing CSV files then I recommend getting them comma delimited (or whatever delimiter you choose) and going the route of making an SSIS package with a corresponding SQL Agent Job that runs daily to check for the file and run it if it finds it.

Info on SSIS package creation:
http://smallbusiness.chron.com/import-csv-ssis-46849.html

If this is a one time load then I would recommend just using the import export wizard built into SQL Server.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

Pretty easy to use the import export wizard too. Right click the database > tasks > import data. This will launch the wizard and will walk you through the one time import.

Adding Microsoft's official SSIS guide as well:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx