# How to insert records in mysql from csv?

Tags: mysql, csv

How to use file load query?

I tried this query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'customer.csv' INTO TABLE customer
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: Also, depending on the error (if any), include a snippet of the csv file and the structure of the customer table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import CSV file to MySQL table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table)

Comment: in csv i have an address column in which ',' occur because of this in my mysql table data move one column to another column.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax:

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name' INTO TABLE `tbl_name` CHARACTER SET [CHARACTER SET charset_name] FIELDS [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}[TERMINATED BY 'string']] [LINES[TERMINATED BY 'string']]
```

Example:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'E:\\wamp\\tmp\\customer.csv' INTO TABLE `customer` CHARACTER SET 'utf8' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
```

Comment: ENCLOSED BY '"' solve my ',' occur problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Please read [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)