# Best way to import large dataset into mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, import

Looking for some help. I have a 300GB csv file that I need to import into a mysql database. Database is running on Centos 7.

I don't know if just doing a basic local-infile is the right way or if there is a better way. Should I split up the csv?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please look this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xppyP5ibbYM

You need to divide into parts and import one by one for more help check this post

https://medium.com/@sanathkumar/import-large-csv-files-to-mysql-in-a-minute-e6d639b790ab#.orpyklvbs

Thanks

Comment: You should provide more details in the post. Only providing links to other sites is frowned upon. [Look](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259)

Comment: Thanks sir #dkeeper09