# How can we populate the CSV data into Mysql database from jenkins

Tags: java, mysql, csv, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm running some tests in Jenkins which will produce CSV report files. So, I need to store the CSV results into Mysql database to query them for my future use. Any of you have any idea that how we can save the CSV data into a database from Jenkins. Is there any plugin for that? If it is not possible with Jenkins can we do that through any java program to pick up a CSV file from a particular location and parse the results to a database which can be run or build using Jenkins I searched throughout the internet but couldn't find anything. Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table it is not jenkins but will help you

Comment: @shreyanshjogi I saw that yesterday, but I don't need a tool. I just need to automate the stuff so my task is to populate the CSV data into Mysql through a Jenkins job

Comment: Then you need to write code which can read your file and insert into database. Once that code is written that you can configure that job in jenkins and just run that.

Comment: Yup. I'm thinking about that as well. But just want to know if there is any other alternative process which can be done through a Jenkins plugin

Comment: Could you post an example of the CSV file?