# How do I insert multiple rows WITHOUT repeating the “INSERT INTO" statement in hibernate java?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, csv

Can I create this type of SQL statement using hibernate in java.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (id,First, Last)
VALUES
(1,'Fred', 'Smith'),
(2'John', 'Smith'),
(3,'Michael', 'Smith'),
(4,'Robert', 'Smith');

INSERT INTO table2 (id,table1_id,age)
VALUES
(11,1, 35),
(12,2,24),
(13,3,32),
(14,3,31);
```

Actually, I am uploading a **.csv** file having very large amount of data. For that I want to create these type of insert statement for speedup the execution of CSV file.

**How can I do so? Or there is any other way to do so?**

Comment: yes you can did you tried something? or you want to start from scratch?

Comment: @YCF_L I WANT TO START FROM SCRATCH.

Comment: Yes, you can try bulk-load database import utilities.

Comment: @RiteshK can you send me the link of it for java hibernate ?

Comment: [LOAD DATA INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24170168/5070879)