# Query to insert rows from CSV to MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, csv

I have 2 tables `employees` and `job` in a `MySQL` server. I have 2 `CSV` files with the same schema as the two tables. Something as below.

**Job table(MySQL)**

[image]

**Job(CSV)**

[image]

**Employees(MySQL)**

[image]

**Employees(CSV)**

[image]

I need to insert the rows from `CSV` into the `MySQL` tables. Note that the `Id` fields in both the tables are on `AUTOINCREMENT`. I am aware that `MySQL` does not support `merge` query and instead has `INSERT.. ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`. Now the issue with using this is that the Primary keys i.e., the Ids are definitely duplicate but I need them to be inserted as new rows with new Ids. For example, the Admin role should have the Id as 3 and so on. Also, as you can see, the `job` table is being referenced by the `employees` table. So the the `JobId` column in the table should be updated with the respective values. I am not sure how this can be achieved.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to import it using mysql or write some kind of program using some programming language.

Comment: I'd prefer it being done with SQL queries and no tools. C# would be okay but like I said, I prefer having queries.

Comment: Then [How to import CSV file to MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table) question might help you

Comment: I don't think it does. The OP wanted to import a single huge file into the table whereas in my case I have foreign-key relationship between the tables. Also I need to insert rows into a table that already holds other rows of data.