# Loading csv files into database in linux

Tags: python, database

I have been scraping **csv files** from the **web** every minute and storing them into a directory.

The files are being named according to the time of retrieval:

```
name = 'train'+str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S"))+'.csv'
```

I need to upload each file into a **database** created on some remote server.

How can I do the above?

Comment: You can use scp to transfer them to the server (https://kb.iu.edu/d/agye) and then use a python script to load the transactions from csv into the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import CSV file to MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table)

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas and sqlalchemy for loading CSV into databases. I use MSSQL and my code looks like this:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa 

server = 'your server'
database = 'your database'

for filename in os.listdir(directory): #iterate over files
    df = pandas.read_csv(filename, sep=',')
    engine = sa.create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://'+server+'/'+database+'? 
    driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0')

    tableName = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]) #removes .csv extension 

    df.to_sql(tableName, con=engine,dtype=None) #sent data to server
```

By setting the dtype parameter you can change the conversion of datatype (e.g. if you want smallint instead of integer, etc)

to ensure you dont write the same file/table twice I would suggest to perhaps keep a logfile in the directory, where you can log what csv files are written to the DB. and then exclude those in your for-loop.

Comment: Does the above code read through each csv file line by line? It isn't reading in mine