# Mobile data refresh

Tags: android, ios

I hope you guys can help me. My friend is designing a mobile app for his restaurant. The menu will be changing daily.... I was just wondering if is there any plugin that would enable us to update or change the menu from a spread sheet or just from a plugin launched from a remote computer? Thank you for your help in advance.

Kind Regards

Comment: Have you tried Firebase. You can add menus in Firebase and show in your app.

Comment: If you are asking for how to read data from a spreadsheet programatically, the easiest way is to export the spreadsheet to CSV and use some kind of CSV library to read it. If you are not limited to using spreadsheet, you should use some kind of database to host your menu and fetch data from the database in the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will be easier to have a spreadsheet in Google Docs and parse it with [G Suite APIs](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/guides/android)

Answer (score 0):

Real time applications would definitely need database, you should however insert the data in the spreadsheet(price,item name,details) so insert the data directly into the database or you can also [import CSV to mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement FireBase, a free real-time database from Google. All the documentation needed for setting it up is available at [firebase.google.com](https://firebase.google.com/).

I've used it for a project, and it works quite well.

In your case, I would recommend either modifying the database manually, or creating a secondary basic app for specifically modifying the menu in the database, which of course only the Restaurant Owner should have (don't publish the APK). This can easily be achieved since 2 different Apps can communicate with the same Firebase database.