# How to import a CSV file into MySQL tables, filtering only rows that meet a condition?

Tags: mysql, csv, import

I have to import a CSV file into MySQL table. The file and the table have the same structure (columns and types of values). The import should happen with following algo:

- read a line from the file,
- compare values from column X (file) with column X (db table),
- import line, if the value in the file is higher, than the value in the db table.

The question is, slightly off-topic: how is it possible to automate this kind of import? Are there tools doing such? Or is PhpMyAdmin enough - create temporal table, put the file into it, compare and import?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import CSV file to MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table)

Comment: I think I would be tempted to import the whole thing first, and then run the comparison.

Comment: @Strawberry you could be right. I mean, it isn't a kind of unique task - i guess, there should be many solutions for it. But i'm struggle with finding a ready and automated one...

Comment: @Sterconium: no, it isn't a duplikate. It is fully other kind of import i want to do, as it is in the topic you cited.

Answer (score 0):

For everybody, who is looking for same or similar solutions:

- The tool, which helps to accomplish such tasks, is calles `webyog` (no link - its not an advertising, search for it),
- The tool has possibility to specify SQL query, which will rule the import.

An answer about this solutions is provided by the tool's support - should work as expected. For me, it will be the accepted solution.