# How to transfer Excel data to My SQL Query Browser?

Tags: sql, excel

I have a problem to transfer Excel data to My SQL Query Browser? Someone can help me with how to transfer Excel data to SQL?

My excel data is store

```
  C:\2019\countries.xlsx
```

My excel data is like below the picture:

[image]

Below is my SQL info, I won't put excel file data to column(id, name,country_code and language):

[image]

I hope anyone can guide me on how to use an easy way to insert data into the database. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import CSV file to MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert into csv then use the below query to import.

```
load data local infile 'C:/2019/countries.csv' into table countries
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"' 
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 lines;
```

You can refer the detail in docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

Note: If using Windows terminate by '\r\n' use '\n' on Linux based OS.