# Can I import csv file to mysql using relative path?

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I'm looking for the way to import csv file into .sql file which are both in same directory. This is because I don't know the exact path where my project will run on.

it will be in something........./db/migration folder.
I tried 'ex.csv', '/ex.csv', './ex.csv', '/db/migration/ex.csv' ..etc.

How can I import it? Or is it impossible?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/ex.csv' INTO TABLE Course
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

> The LOCAL modifier affects where the file is expected to be found:
>
> If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the
>   client host and sent to the server. The file can be given as a full
>   path name to specify its exact location. If given as a relative path
>   name, the name is interpreted relative to the directory in which the
>   client program was started.

So you should be able to give a relative path the the place where the program was started.