# Importing CSV file to HeidiSQL, error 1148

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, heidisql

I'm completely novice to MySQL, and I'm trying to load some CSV sheets to the server using HeidiSQL -> tools -> Import CSV. But it keeps giving me this error:

> Error 1148: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version".

Is there a way to fix that, or maybe another way to load a CSV?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import CSV file to MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-to-import-csv-file-to-mysql-table)

Answer (score 0):

For query based csv import you can use `load data ...` to load csv files.

For more info refer [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html)

**Example:**

To skip the first line which is header in `csv` you can use `ignore 1 lines`

```
load data local infile 'D:std_table.csv' into table local.student
fields terminated by ','
enclosed by '"' 
lines terminated by '\r\n'
ignore 1 lines;
```

For windows based system use `\r\n` for line termination and for Linux use `\n`

**Side Note:**

You could try using `MySQL Workbench` for `MySQL` from official site [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/).

Answer (score -1):

try this one:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/discounts.csv' 
INTO TABLE discounts 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

Comment: It won't help OP. since `MySQL` <> `SQL Server`