# Convert csv Import in datagrip to SQL script

Tags: mysql, csv, import, datagrip

I am using the Import Data Tool From DataGrip well, and I would know if is that possible, after loading a CSV file, to get the SQL script that used to do the import like 
LOAD DATA IN FILE...
or how can I write the script by matching the DataGrip Import CV parameter to the SQL LOAD DATA parameters like SEPARATOR, TERMINATED BY ...

For a better understand I am facing the same problem as here and would to know if it's possible to do the same with DataGrip instead of HeidiSQL

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3635318/8280536

Comment: Hi, its not really clear what you are asking. Can you show us an example of what you want to get out from whatever you are asking please

Comment: updated the post

Answer (score 0):

At the moment DataGrip doesn't support the mentioned feature.

I filed [a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-10980) based on your description.