# Creating table and importing data from csv/excel to MySQL error

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep receiving errors that my data is too long when trying to import a CSV dataset into MySQL.

I created the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Master_SA(
    Yr_Month TEXT,
    Employee_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Role_Detail TEXT,
    Manager_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Sales_Region VARCHAR(50),
    Ramp_Status VARCHAR(8),
    Office_Location VARCHAR(10),
    Rep_A_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Rep_B_Name VARCHAR(50),
    Tenure_in_Months INT,
    Number_of_Touches_Completed INT,
    Calls INT,
    Connected INT,
    Total_Talk_Time INT,
    Total_Number_of_Initial_Opportunities INT,
    Number_of_Demos_Held INT,
    Number_of_Initial_Wins INT,
    Number_of_Total_Wins INT,
    Avg_Time_of_Connected_Calls TEXT,
    Connect_Rate TEXT,
    Show_Rate TEXT,
    Initial_Wins_Demo TEXT
);
```

And this is a screenshot of the CSV file

[image]

Comment: Hey, I found how to export data from CSV file to MySQL. You can go through the below link and try exporting by any one method. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635166/how-do-i-import-csv-file-into-a-mysql-table)

Comment: Or, Please choose correct datatype while creating the table.

Comment: *I keep receiving errors that my data is too long* You must provide complete error message text, not a tale about it. *this is a screenshot of the CSV file* This is Excel worksheet, not CSV file screenshot.